# Can't ping specific device

Tags: networking, dns, wireless-networking

I have these nodes on the same network

- Sasmung GT-S5300 192.168.12.38
- Asus Zenfone 5   192.168.12.37
- pc(windows 7)    192.168.12.36

  1. I tried to access my **pc** with my **samsung** through web browser, and it works but not with my **asus**.
  2. I tried to access my **asus** with my **samsung** through web browser, and it works but not with my **pc**.
  3. I tried to ping my **asus** with my **pc** but it gets timed out.
  4. I tried to ping my **asus** with *other* **pc** and it works.

Nothing appears wrong when I used arp and the firewall is off.

Can anyone help me why my pc can't communicate with my asus?

Thanks

Comment: I understand from your question you're trying to ping and browse your phones and the other way around.  Keep in mind that most phones will not have the ping service enabled or allowed and also won't have a http server enabled.

Comment: What devices (from the list above) are wireless and what devices are wired? What network device is in-between the two (as in wireless router, switch, wireless access point)?